# Google Map API v2 is not working on genymotion

Tags: android, google-maps, genymotion

My Android code using Google Map API v2 is not working on genymotion. I have developed this code and run on my PC and it works fine, but the same code I am trying in my laptop then it gives me error "app has unfortunately stopped". I checked my code 100 times and it's perfect, everything is perfect in configuration at Google API console.

I have installed Google Play service in genymotion using following links:
http://filetrip.net/dl?4SUOrdcMRv
http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Google_Apps#gappsCM11

Logcat output:

```
09-04 20:07:15.691: E/AndroidRuntime(2728): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-04 20:07:15.691: E/AndroidRuntime(2728): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to           instantiate activity    ComponentInfo{com.example.geolocation/com.example.geolocation.MainActivity}:   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.geolocation.MainActivity" on  path: /data/app/com.example.geolocation-2.apk
09-04 20:07:15.691: E/AndroidRuntime(2728):     at  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
09-04 20:07:15.691: E/AndroidRuntime(2728):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
09-04 20:07:15.691: E/AndroidRuntime(2728):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-04 20:07:15.691: E/AndroidRuntime(2728):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
09-04 20:07:15.691: E/AndroidRuntime(2728):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-04 20:07:15.691: E/AndroidRuntime(2728):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-04 20:07:15.691: E/AndroidRuntime(2728):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
09-04 20:07:15.691: E/AndroidRuntime(2728):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-04 20:07:15.691: E/AndroidRuntime(2728):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-04 20:07:15.691: E/AndroidRuntime(2728):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-04 20:07:15.691: E/AndroidRuntime(2728):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-04 20:07:15.691: E/AndroidRuntime(2728):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-04 20:07:15.691: E/AndroidRuntime(2728): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.geolocation.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.example.geolocation-2.apk
09-04 20:07:15.691: E/AndroidRuntime(2728):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
09-04 20:07:15.691: E/AndroidRuntime(2728):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
09-04 20:07:15.691: E/AndroidRuntime(2728):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
09-04 20:07:15.691: E/AndroidRuntime(2728):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
09-04 20:07:15.691: E/AndroidRuntime(2728):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
09-04 20:07:15.691: E/AndroidRuntime(2728):     ... 11 more
```